# How to populate an input field with the time left before an event occurs using javascript and Date objects

Tags: javascript, datetime

So, I have a bug in my code somewhere. The "countdown" function needs to return a text string displaying the number of days, hours, minutes, and seconds between a starting date and a stopping date. The "changeYear" function needs to change a date's year value if the date has already been passed in the calendar year.

Something is amiss because, the text fields are not populating with the time left in days:hrs:min:sec for each event. Only thing that's showing up is the current date in the "thisDay" field. You can see this in my http://jsfiddle.net/gPjys/ jsfiddle where the "Countdown to Event" fields are blank.

Also, see the "HERE MAY BE WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES" in the following code:

```
    function showCountdown(){
        var today = new Date();
        var Date1 = "Jan 14, 2011 at 10:00 a.m.";
        var Date2 = "May 21, 2011 at 12:00 p.m.";
        var Date3 = "Jul 4, 2011 at 9:00 p.m.";
        var Date4 = "Sep 1, 2011 at 12:00 p.m.";
        var Date5 = "Dec 1, 2011 at 11:30 a.m.";
        var Date6 = "Dec 31, 2011 at 3:30 p.m.";   
        document.eventform.thisDay.value = showDateTime(today);
        changeYear(today, Date1);
        changeYear(today, Date2);
        changeYear(today, Date3);
        changeYear(today, Date4);
        changeYear(today, Date5);
        changeYear(today, Date6);
        document.eventform.count1.value = countdown(today, Date1);
        document.eventform.count2.value = countdown(today, Date2); 
        document.eventform.count3.value = countdown(today, Date3); 
        document.eventform.count4.value = countdown(today, Date4); 
        document.eventform.count5.value = countdown(today, Date5);
        document.eventform.count6.value = countdown(today, Date6);
}


    function showDateTime(time) {
        date = time.getDate();
        month = time.getMonth()+1;
        year = time.getFullYear();

        second = time.getSeconds();
        minute = time.getMinutes();
        hour = time.getHours();

        ampm = (hour < 12) ? " a.m." : " p.m.";
        hour = (hour > 12) ? hour - 12 : hour;
        hour = (hour === 0) ? 12 : hour;

        minute = minute < 10 ? "0"+minute : minute;
        second = second < 10 ? "0"+second : second;

        return month+"/"+date +"/"+year+" at "+hour+":"+minute+":"+second+ampm;
    }

    //HERE MAY BE WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES

    function changeYear(today, holiday){
    /*
        insert a function named 'changeYear' that will
        change a date's year value if the date has already been 
        passed in the current calendar year
    */

        var year = today.getFullYear();

    //The holiday parameter is used to store the date object representing one of the
    //events in the event column of the form

        holiday.setFullYear(year);
        holiday = (holiday < today) ? year += 1 : year;
        holiday.setFullYear(year);
    }

    function countdown(start, stop){
    /*
      will return a text string displaying the number of days,
      hours, minutes, and seconds between a starting date and a
      stopping date. 
    */  

        var time = stop - start;

    /*
      convert the time difference into days, hours, minutes, seconds
      and return the following text string
      days days, hours hrs, minutes mins, seconds secs   
    */

        var days = time.getDate();
        var hours = (days - Math.floor(days))*24;
        var minutes = (hours - Math.floor(hours))*60;
        var seconds = (minutes - Math.floor(minutes))*60;

        return days + "days" + hours + "hrs" + minutes + "mins" + seconds + "secs";
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gPjys/

Thanks in advance! Cheers!
-QS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem. The function must be:

```
function changeYear(today, holiday){
    var todayYear = today.getFullYear();
    holiday.setFullYear(todayYear);
    if(today > holiday){        
        holiday.setFullYear(todayYear + 1);
    }    
}
```

And it works. But I also changed many other things, check here: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/gPjys/2/

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: Gee, thanks Edgar. I was also able to get the value of days left to be included in the text field by adding this line of code to the countdown function: `var hours = parseInt(days/24)` directly after `var days = parseInt((time/1000)/86400);` Still trying to figure out how to calculate the minutes and seconds left until events occur.